# Connect Node.js BOT to MS Azure SQL database

Tags: node.js, azure-sql-database, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a working MS Teams bot written in Node.js. The bot asks a series of questions and currently displays the responses at the end by accessing the session variables. All well and good.

Now I am attempting to store the session variables in a MS Azure SQL DB. The DB is correctly set up in Azure as I can access and write data to it in SSMS. But I believe I am probably connecting incorrectly to the DB in my bot code. The bot code I am using is pulled from:

[connecting to SQL using Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-2017)

That code makes sense to me. But how do I use that code in my bot? Here is what I have attempted thus far...

Currently I am using the local memory MemoryBotStorage() and setting to that.

```
var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();
.set('storage', inMemoryStorage)
```

In another Microsoft [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state-azure-cosmosdb) dealing with the Azure Cosmos DB it states "4.Specify that you want to use your custom database instead of the in-memory storage." So from this I deduce that I hafta add my instantiated sql db to the .set('storage', DB Goes Here) but my attempts have failed and I am not sure if I am even correct?

So my question is how do I correctly access the Azure sql server DB form my bot code - and is the link I provided even the correct way?

Thank you

Note - This code [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs) worked for me  - I was able to connect and query my Azure DB - but it is only DB code and does not take into consideration bot code.

EDIT - Code:

```
const builder = require('botbuilder');
const builderTeams = require('botbuilder-teams');
const restify = require('restify');

const connector = new builderTeams.TeamsChatConnector(
    {

        appId: "My app ID,
        appPassword: "My App PW",
    }

);

var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();


const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    function (session) {
    session.send("Welcome.");
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "Question1?");
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.question1 = results.response;
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "Question2?");
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.Question2 = results.response;
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "Question3?");
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.Question3 = results.response;

    // Begin DB

    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
    var config = {
        userName: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypw',
        server: 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        // If you are on Azure SQL Database, you need these next options.  
        options: { encrypt: true, database: 'mydb' }
    };
    var connection = new Connection(config);
    connection.on('connect', function (err) {
        // If no error, then good to proceed.  
        console.log("Connected");
        executeStatement1();
    });

    var Request = require('tedious').Request
    var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

    function executeStatement1() {
        request = new Request("INSERT my (Username, Question1, Question2, Question3, StatusDate) VALUES (@Username, @Question1, @Question2, @Question3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);", function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
        request.addParameter('Username', TYPES.NVarChar, session.userData.userName);
        request.addParameter('Question1', TYPES.NVarChar, session.dialogData.Question1);
        request.addParameter('Question2', TYPES.NVarChar, session.dialogData.Question2);
        request.addParameter('Question3', TYPES.NVarChar, session.dialogData.Question3);
        request.on('row', function (columns) {
            columns.forEach(function (column) {
                if (column.value === null) {
                    console.log('NULL');
                } else {
                    console.log("ID of inserted item is " + column.value);
                }
            });
        });
        connection.execSql(request);

    // End DB


    // Process request and display details
    session.endDialog();
}
]).set('storage', inMemoryStorage)


const server = restify.createServer();
server.post('api/messages', connector.listen());
server.listen(portnumber)
```

Error when running with npm start:

```
npm start

> simplebot@1.0.0 start C:\Developer\dailyStatus
> node index.js

C:\Developer\dailyStatus\index.js:81
]).set('storage', inMemoryStorage)
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! simplebot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the simplebot@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely...    

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C: etc.
```

**FINAL**

I was able to able to get this working with this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs). Thanks also to Marc LeFleur.

Comment: You don't mention what you're getting for a result. Is there an error? Where is it failing for you?

Comment: Good point - adding now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several typos. For example, you're missing the closing `"` on `appId`:

```
const connector = new builderTeams.TeamsChatConnector(
    {    
        appId: "My app ID",
        appPassword: "My App PW",
    }

);
```

You also can't declare the `function executeStatement1() {...}` function *within* the your `IDialogWaterfallStep` function. This needs to live outside the constructor and *called* from the `IDialogWaterfallStep`.

Comment: Thank you - I will test that out. I should mention that the typos is where I "sanitized" the code to remove personal info like passwords etc. I just did that in a hurry in Notepad++.

Comment: I was unable to get this to work with the code from my 1st link. The 2nd link works along with your comment about having the function outside the constructor. The reason that I did this is I think I got confused with the way dialogs work. Everything seems to "drop though" to the next statement so I thought that perhaps that would be the case with the DB code as well. As I say it is working but IDK how to pass the session variables to the SQL function. I will ask that in another post. TYVM